# Add 4 hours for current time in date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I add 4 hours from my date-time pickers' `startDate` to `endDate`?

```
$(function() {
    $('#startDate').datetimepicker();
    $('#endDate').datetimepicker();
    $("#startDate").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        $('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#endDate").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        $('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.date` objects are instances of `Moment`. As you can see [in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/), you can use the `.add` and `.subtract` functions on them:

```
$('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date.add(4, 'hours'));
// ...
$('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date.subtract(4, 'hours'));
```

---

As for the comments:

To set the default date, use the `defaultDate` option. It works with both `Moment`s and native `Date`s:

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({ defaultDate: Date() });
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: $('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").date().add(4, 'hours')
});
```

Also get rid of the `dp.change` event handlers, you don't need those callbacks just to set the default date. Unless of course you want to keep them linked, then use the `dp.change` but use the `date` function instead of the `setMinDate` and `setMaxDate`:

```
$("#startDate").on("dp.change", function(e) {
    $('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(4, 'hours'));
});
```

Beware an infinite loop if you want to link them like that both ways, calling `date` with a different date will trigger a new `dp.change`. While that shouldn't happen in your setup, it may start to if you tweak it slightly.

Comment: hi this snippet not working for me as we select start date picker it will show current system time and in the end picker it will automatically add 4 hours to current time and it will show

Comment: The question's asking about the *max* and *min* date. What does the displayed datetime have to do with anything?

Comment: hi ,their is no change in output after adding snippet so my requirement is assume we have to datetimepickers in first we have current time and date defaulty and in another we need to add 4 hours to that current time . example in first picker 22/09/2015 4:27PM then in second picker 22/09/2015 8:27PM we need ,,thank you for your help

Comment: Ok, edited that in the answer. However you really should edit this into the question, as it has *nothing* to do with the original post. You may also like to read through [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this is also not working for me anyway thank you i will try to ask questions in structured way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
To add minutes:

```
$('#Start').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(30, 'minutes'));
```

To add hours:

```
 $('#Start').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(4, 'hours'));
```

Also with below script, you can compare start and end date, and if they were equal or start date time was after end date time, you set your default date time again based on new selected date time by user, I always set the default date time on server side:

```
//Server side default setup for first run
Start = DateTime.Now;
End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
```

And here is the js script:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(function()
        {         
         $('#Start').datetimepicker({
                            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
                        });
         $('#End').datetimepicker({
                            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
                        });
         $('#Start').on("dp.change",
                            function(e)
                            {
                                if (dateSorter($('#End').val(), $(this).val()) === -1 || dateSorter($('#End').val(), $(this).val()) === 0)
                                    // if ($('#End').val() < $(this).val())
                                {
                                 //   console.log("End date "+$('#End').val()+ " is before start date: "+ $(this).val());
                                    $('#End').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(30, 'minutes'));
                                }
                               // add your other scripts for example update something on the page, updateAvailableSeats();
                            });
      $('#End').on("dp.change",
                            function(e)
                            {
                                if (dateSorter($('#Start').val(), $(this).val()) === 1 || dateSorter($('#Start').val(), $(this).val()) === 0)
                                    // if ($('#Start').val() > $(this).val())
                                {
                                 //   console.log("Start date " + $('#Start').val() + " is after end date: " + $(this).val());
                                    $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(30, 'minutes'));
                                }
                            });
      //  updateAvailableSeats();
    });
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks